# C++ typecasting when passing std::string as function argument

Tags: c++

Is passing a string by `""` equivalent to passing a string by calling `std::str("")` in C++?

e.g. given a function which accepts `std::str` as an argument:

```
void funcA(std::string arg) {
    arg = "abc";
}
```

Should I call it by `funcA(std::string("abc"));` or `funcA("abc");` ?  i.e. is the second version a typecast from an array of char?

Comment: #5: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: question is, is the second version's argument treated as an array of char instead?

Comment: @toiletfreak - `string` is just an array of chars, but in nicer wrapping

Comment: Please don't put C tags on C++ programs.

Comment: @PabloLemurr Nah, not even close.

Comment: @H2CO3 - so you tell me than I lived in lie whole my life? D:

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but this discussion is interesting and vaguely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727412/inconsistency-between-stdstring-and-string-literals

Comment: Both work.  In FuncA("abc") the compiler adds the call to string( const char * ) for you.

Comment: @PabloLemurr Kind of. `string` and `char []` are two very distinct data types, and although they represent the same concept (character strings), when discussing a question like this, the difference is not negligible.

Comment: @PabloLemurr An array in C++ is a data type containing a fixed number of objects of the same type. A `std::string` maintains a variable number of characters in a contiguous block of memory. Quite different, but same in terms of pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent. Because the constructor `std::string::string( char const * )` is not declared as `explicit`, it is called *implicitly* to provide a conversion from `char *` to `string`. The implicit call does the same thing as the explicit call (written out as `std::string("abc")`).